# No me realiza la suma de filas en Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, input

Es la primera vez que publico aquí, de antemano doy gracias a las posibles respuestas o ayuda que reciba; mi problema es el siguiente:
Tengo un modal con un formulario, dentro del formulario hay una tabla con varias columnas, tres de ellas son "Debe", "Haber" y "Debe + Haber". En cada fila de "debe" y "haber" el usuario introduce valores numéricos y al lado aparece la suma correspondiente de ambas filas en "debe + haber". (Agregué un botón para probar llamando a la función correspondiente)
Resulta que no aparece el valor total de la sumatoria, únicamente sale 0 y he probado mil formas de realizar esa simple suma pero no consigo realizarla, siento que quizás es un error de novata pero no logro ver cuál es el fallo. Dejaré a continuación lo que tengo en esa parte:

En modal.component.ts tengo (he inicializado todos esos valores a 0):

```
sumar(){
this.resultado = this.valordebe + this.valorhaber }
```

En modal.component.html tengo:

```
<td>
 <input [(ngModel)]="valordebe" (keypress)="onlyNum($event)" type="number" class="form-control" >
</td>
<td>
  <input [(ngModel)]="valorhaber" (keypress)="onlyNum($event)" type="number" class="form-control" >
</td>
<td>
  <button type="button" class="btn" (click)="sumar()">SUMAR</button>
  <input type="number" class="form-control" value={{resultado}} readonly>
</td>
```

Comment: Hola Valentina, te doy la bienvenida a la comunidad, esperamos poder ser de ayuda. Te pregunto, si entendí lo que estás tratando de hacer es, una tabla, con nuna sola fila, donde la fila debe sumar el valor de las dos columnas *debe* + *haber*?

Comment: Si es así, por favor revisa el [siguiente enlace](https://angular-ivy-zsw3ul.stackblitz.io/) si realiza según lo que planteas, en caso contrario me lo haces saber

Comment: @jecorrales Sii, es exactamente lo que necesito, y de lo forma que lo estoy haciendo no me funciona

Comment: @jecorrales Siiiii, al principio no se me abría el código, solo el ejecutable directamente, pero ya pude verlo y realizarlo, me funcionó a la perfección, muchísimas gracias. Mi error era que en los {{ }} ponía el resultado, no volvía a realizar la operación de suma, gracias!

Comment: Con gusto, por favor podrías marcar la respuesta como aceptada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes dos formas posibles de hacerlo desde la directiva `ngModel` de angular. Podrías utilizar una suma automática con los dos valores que requieres sumar:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Debe</th>
    <th>Haber</th>
    <th>Debe + Haber</th>
  </tr>
  <!-- SUMA DE VALORES AUTOMÁTICAMENTE -->
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input
        type="number"
        [(ngModel)]="valorDebe"
        name="valorDebe"
        placeholder="Debe (valor)"
      />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input
        type="number"
        [(ngModel)]="valorHaber"
        name="valorHaber"
        placeholder="Haber (valor)"
      />
    </td>
    <td>
      <!-- TOTAL -->
      {{ valorDebe + valorHaber }}
      <!-- SI VAS A SUMAR DOS INPUT DE TIPO TEXT TENDRIAS QUE USAR EL OPERADOR -- PARA SUMAR AMBOS VALORES -->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

La siguiente alternativa sería calcular el resultado al momento de ejecutar un evento `(click)`, esto quiere decir que al momento de ingresar el valor para `valorDebe` + `valorHaber` se almacena en una tercer variable `total` al momento de ejecutar el método correspondiente `sumarValores()`:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Debe</th>
    <th>Haber</th>
    <th>Debe + Haber</th>
  </tr>
  <!-- SUMAR VALORES POR MEDIO DE UN EVENTO ONCLICK -->
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input
        type="number"
        [(ngModel)]="valorDebe"
        name="valorDebe"
        placeholder="Debe (valor)"
      />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input
        type="number"
        [(ngModel)]="valorHaber"
        name="valorHaber"
        placeholder="Haber (valor)"
      />
    </td>
    <td>
      {{ total }}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />
<!-- BUTTON QUE EJECUTA EL METODO DE SUMA DE VALORES -->
<button (click)="sumarValores()">Sumar valores</button>
```

Para almacenar el valor en un `input` podrías asignarlo directamente a otra directiva:

```
<input
      type="number"
      [(ngModel)]="total"
      name="total"
      placeholder="Total (valor)"
    />
```

Y este sería el `ts` del componente:

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  valorDebe: number = 0;
  valorHaber: number = 0;
  total: number = 0;

  sumarValores() {
    this.total = this.valorDebe + this.valorHaber;
  }
}
```

**STACKBLITZ.COM**

En el siguiente enlace [puedes ver el ejemplo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zsw3ul) funcional